# Error using object created with Ctype(....)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to update records in my database(`MySQL`) on vb.net. I wanted to update record according to the text boxes. I am using loop since I have multiple text boxes with a different name for qty and price using Ctype.
A sample of my code is:

```
j=58
For i As Integer = 1 To 19 Step 1
        Dim pricebox As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("TextBox" + CStr(i)), TextBox)
        Dim qtybox As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("TextBox" + CStr(j)), TextBox)

        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i)
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", CInt(qtybox.Text))
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", CInt(pricebox.Text))
        j=j-1
Next
```

But during runtime, it throws:

> "object reference not set to an instance" on line
>   "sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", CInt(qtybox.Text))"

Any help would be appreciated heartly, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: but i cannot create new instance for "qtybox" using "new". how do i do it then?

Comment: That's not the only thing the post tells you to do, you know. You've got to find out _what_ is null, and also what _the cause_ of it being null is... It's all explained in there.

Comment: yes but i cant figure out actual method to solve it or what caused it so :(

Comment: That's what the post is about. There are various answers with different explanations about how you can find out what is null and what caused it. To start with: Have you determined what object/variable is null?

Comment: thanks by the way for guiding me to that post :D

Comment: When you get the exception, look at the value of "TextBox" + CStr(j) and see if that control actually exists with that name.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i did :)

```
Dim pricebox = New TextBox
Dim qtybox = New TextBox
pricebox = CType(Me.Controls("TextBox" + CStr(i)), TextBox)
qtybox = CType(Me.Controls("TextBox" + CStr(j)), TextBox)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it should behave any differently than the original posted above.

Comment: Those New don't make any sense as to why it's working now.

Comment: As others have mentioned: this isn't right. And as I (implicitly) mentioned before: _Using `New` is not always the answer!_ The reason you would have gotten an NRE is either because `qtybox` is null, or `qtybox.Text`. What you have changed shouldn't fix anything since you re-set those variables right after.

Comment: i dont know why it worked but it worked. and also i used recursion instead of loop. otherwise it would give that query error because it is defined many time :D

Comment: @Bhuwanpandey recursion for that? I think you should reconsider. Just calling a function in your loop would be better.